# htaccess redirection implied html extension not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've tried many things before coming here, it should be a simple problem, but there is something I miss for sure.

I want to redirect a bunch of URLs to another ones, one by one, and here is an example in my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /index.php/Microcontrôleurs_Généralités https://newdomain.org/Microcontrôleurs_Généralités
```

The thing is that the old URLs are files in a *real* folder "index.php" but with ".html" extension.
When I go to [https://olddomain.org/Microcontrôleurs_Généralités](https://olddomain.org/Microcontr%C3%B4leurs_G%C3%A9n%C3%A9ralit%C3%A9s), apache serves me the implied .html file. I can go to [https://olddomain.org/Microcontrôleurs_Généralités.html](https://olddomain.org/Microcontr%C3%B4leurs_G%C3%A9n%C3%A9ralit%C3%A9s.html) too, it's the same file on disk.

But my redirection as above does not redirect anything.
If I add the .html extension to the file like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /index.php/Microcontrôleurs_Généralités.html https://newdomain.org/Microcontrôleurs_Généralités
```

Then, if I go to the URL with explicit ".html" at end, it is redirected correctly, but if I miss the .html, apache says the URL was not found.

I've turned this in my head numerous times, I can't figure out the real problem.

Help would be much apreciated, thx.

Comment: Still no solution for this, it seems to be quite simple, but there is something I miss...